# How do i send a value from my async task to another new activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, google-cloud-platform

I am calling convertResponseToString in my async task however i also have a button, how do i get the logo.feature to show the ouput in a new activity?
Basically i want to show the message in a new activity. Any suggestions?

```
> 'public String convertResponseToString(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse
> response) {
>         String message = "I FOUND THESE THINGS = :\n\n";
> 
>         List<EntityAnnotation> logos = response.getResponses().get(0).getLogoAnnotations();
>         List<EntityAnnotation> labels = response.getResponses().get(0).getLabelAnnotations();
>         if (logos != null) {
>             for (EntityAnnotation logo : logos) {
>                 String s = logo.getDescription();
>                 EditText logodesc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
>                 logodesc.setText(s);
>                 message += String.format(Locale.US, "The score is : %.3f & The logo detected is : %s ",
> logo.getScore(),logo.getDescription());
>                 message += "\n\n";
>             }
>         } else {
>             message += "NOTHING FOUND!\n";
>         }
>         if(labels !=null) {
>             for (EntityAnnotation label : labels) {
>                 message += String.format(Locale.US, "The score is: %.3f & The label detected is : %s ", label.getScore(),
> label.getDescription());
>                 message += "\n";
>             }
>         }else{
>             message += "NOTHING FOUND!";
>         }
>         return message;
> 
>     }
>     public void init()
>     {
>         mbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
>         mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View view) {
>                 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Result.class);
>                 i.putExtra("Logo");
>                 startActivity(i);
>             }
>         });
>     }
```

> }'

Answer (score 0):

On your first Activity when you click the button then you can send the value from next activity like this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Result.class);     
i.putExtra("Logo","whatever message you want to sent");                      
startActivity(i);
```

Now how can you get the value of these previous value? For this, on your Result Activity get the values like this

```
Intent data =getIntent();
String message= data.getStringExtra("Logo");
```